# temporary file not found in sh script

Tags: shell-script, shell

Take a look at this script first:

```bash
touch test.txt
touch loc

echo "result1" > loc
loc >> test.txt

echo "result2" > loc
loc >> test.txt

rm loc
```

I create two files.  One of them, `loc`, is temporary and I try to write to it but get the following error message:

```
5: script.sh: loc: not found
8: script.sh: loc: not found
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: `loc` is not a command! Use `cat loc` at line 5 and 8.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Redirection operator expects a string or stream of characters as input side and a file on the other side. So you need to use `cat` command to first read the file and then redirect the stream characters to the output file.

```
touch test.txt
touch loc
echo "result1" > loc
cat loc >> test.txt
echo "result2" > loc
cat loc >> test.txt
rm loc
```

Comment: `more` is a pager, intended for interactive use. Instead you should use `cat` for this kind of action.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't know that. I am changing `more` by `cat`..

Answer (score 10):

`loc` is not a command. You would need to use `cat loc >> test.txt` to append it to text.txt. Otherwise you can also avoid the temp file completely:

```
echo "result1" >> test.txt
echo "result2" >> test.txt
```

Note, `touch test.txt` seems also useless.

Answer (score -1):

this will create the test.txt

```
echo "result1" |  tee -a  test.txt
echo "result2" |  tee -a  test.txt
```

OR use this in 1-step

```
echo "result1" && echo "result2" |  tee -a  test.txt
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.